# Pyspark dataframe to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

am getting the below

> Error While converting pyspark Dataframe to Pandas Dataframe

Code:

```
some_df = sc.parallelize([
 ("A", "no"),
 ("B", "yes"),
 ("B", "yes"),
 ("B", "no")]
 ).toDF(["user_id", "phone_number"])

pandas_df = some_df.toPandas()
```

Error: **Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o104.collectToPython.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its running fine in my system I checked it, this error comes when spark want to load all the data into driver memory so probably you don't have enough memory increase your driver memory that should solve the problem or clear the garbage using `gc.collect()` let me know if that helps.